# php codeigniter array values not storing properly in database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter,And I am passing some array values like slno,age,etc
When i store It is store like this ..(End of file also i am getting one comma)

```
Sl No:1,2,3,
age :23,25,28,
```

Here is the code

```
$slno=implode(",",$this->input->post('slno'));
```

can you guys help me how do i store

```
 Slno: 1,2,3
age:23,25,28
```

I don't want comma in end of the string,

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtrim`

```
rtrim($string,',');
```

---

**Example**

```
$string = "23,25,28,";
echo rtrim($string,',')
```

**Program Output**

```
23,25,28
```

[Check the Preview - https://eval.in](https://eval.in/590808) and read [PHP `rtrim()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$slno=substr(0,strlen(implode(",",$this->input->post('slno'))-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()`

```
$string = ",23,25,28,";
echo trim($string,',');
```

Ans

```
23,25,28
```